# How to fix killer instinct 2013 (windows 10, windows store) multiplayer service login error?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, killer-instinct-2013, microsoft-store

"multiplayer service log in error

unable to log in to multiplayer service please try again "

I get the above error message when trying to matchmake or search for a match online on windows 10, windows store killer instinct (free version). I don't have any paid xbox subscriptions.

I have checked that

- xbox live auth manager, and networkign services are active under the services menu
- run the "check" and "fix it" options from Xbox Networking
- relaunching the game (after fix it or restarting computer)
- restarted computer after doing the above
- windows firewall is on
- confirmed I do not have "Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter" under my Network Adapters list in device manager

What other diagnostics can I run and how do I fix this error?

Comment: I will guess there was an outage. The KI Twitter is talking about a fix going live 2 hours ago. https://twitter.com/KillerInstinct?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor No word on when the issue started, but 12 hours to fix such an issue for a mainly online game would be weird.

Comment: There is a reddit thread about it too, so I guess you are not alone with the issue. https://www.reddit.com/r/killerinstinct/comments/plaf88/anyone_else_having_this_issue/

Comment: Putting this here for rereview later: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/Hardware-Network/connect-network/troubleshoot-party-chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fredy31 was right it was an outage